# HashMap getting key given that I already have the key

Tags: java, hashmap

This sounds like a really weird request but I have a `HashMap` of a custom class. I've overridden the `equals` and `hashCode` methods to only focus on certain fields, so that I can pull a key if it equals a new key with the same certain fields. In that case, I want to replace the other fields with some new values. The structure is like so:

```
public class ExampleClass() {
   int field1;
   int field2;

   <insert constructor here with field1 and field2>

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) { // Only return true if field1 is equal
      ...
      return (this.field1 == obj.field1);
   }
}
```

So I use it like this:

```
HashMap<ExampleClass, int> hmap = new HashMap<>();
while(true) {
   ...
   ExampleClass oldObject = new ExampleClass(1, 2);
   ExampleClass newObject = new ExampleClass(1, 5);

   hmap.put(oldObject, 10);
   if(hmap.contains(newObject)) {
      // Get field1 of old object and change it
   }
}
```

This was a bad example but I just want to be able to retrieve the key object of a key-value pair in a `HashMap` given that I have the key so that I can modify the key. How would I do so?

Edit: My hashcode function.

```
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + 
            ((this.srcVertex.getVertexData().getID() == null) ? 0 : this.srcVertex.getVertexData().getID().hashCode());
    result = prime * result + 
            ((this.targetVertex.getVertexData().getID() == null) ? 0 : this.targetVertex.getVertexData().getID().hashCode());
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: `map.put(newkey, map.get(oldkey));`?  I'm not quite sure what you mean by "modify the key".

Comment: you should use a key class that only contains actually equal object, and use your more complex object as a value

Comment: I want to be able to, given the hashmap and newkey, retrieve the oldkey object.

Comment: `public class ExampleClass(){` should be `public class ExampleClass{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you have a key object in the HashMap, and you want to use an "equal" key object to retrieve the key rather than the value it's associated with. There is no method on a HashMap to do that, and it somewhat violates the idea of two objects being "equal" if you do actually care which of the two equal objects you get.

I think it would make more sense to do this in a different way:

- Write a new class `ExampleKey` with just the fields that you want to use in the `equals`/`hashCode` methods for the purposes of the HashMap. This class must override `equals` and `hashCode` using those fields, and it should be immutable (the behaviour is undefined if a key's hash can change while it's in the HashMap).
- Give `ExampleClass` a `getKey()` method which returns an `ExampleKey` object for the current object. It is probably simpler to use [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) here, so that `ExampleClass` doesn't duplicate those fields.
- Now have two HashMaps: a `Map<ExampleKey, Integer>` for the actual mapping that you want to store, and a separate `Map<ExampleKey, ExampleClass>` storing the object which would otherwise have been used as the key in the other HashMap.

Example usage:

```java
Map<ExampleKey, Integer> actualMapping = new HashMap<>();
Map<ExampleKey, ExampleClass> objsUsed = new HashMap<>();
while(true) {
   // ...
   ExampleClass oldObject = new ExampleClass(1, 2);
   ExampleClass newObject = new ExampleClass(1, 5);

   // always update both maps together, to ensure valid state
   actualMapping.put(oldObject.getKey(), 10);
   objsUsed.put(oldObject.getKey(), oldObject);

   // ...

   ExampleClass objUsed = objsUsed.get(newObject.getKey());
   if(objUsed != null) {
        // objUsed == oldObject here
   }
}
```

If you don't care about the philosophy of what "equal" is supposed to mean, then you can apply this same solution without the `ExampleKey` class or the `getKey` method; just use the objects themselves, i.e. `objsUsed` would be of type `Map<ExampleClass, ExampleClass>` and it would always map an object to itself. But I think if you do that, readers of your code will be scratching their heads wondering why you are mapping objects to themselves.

Comment: I have definitely backed myself into a tough spot here. I want to be able to detect when only one field of a custom object with multiple fields is different, then replace that field using a data structure that is better than O(n) time. Maybe I need to just do a complete re-design. Thank you for your informative answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define the hashCode() method. Without it, storing an object as a key in a HashMap doesn't work.

UPDATE:

If srcVertex is field1 and targetVertex is field2, then your hashCode() method is incorrect. If equals() compares srcVertex, then hashCode() should use only srcVertex, not targetVertex.

The rule is: if 2 objects are equal, then their hash codes must be equal.

Comment: I did, but I just didn't bother to put it in the post as I thought it really didn't mean much to the question I had.

Comment: @Stephen Please post your hashCode() because it's probably incorrect.

Comment: I didn't really want to post my actual code because it's very long across multiple files and so wouldn't make sense when viewing only portions. field1 and field2 don't correspond to srcVertex and targetVertex. srcVertex and targetVertex are both field1 in a sense for my code. Thank you for your time however!

Comment: @Stephen Anyway the rule is: if 2 objects are equal, then their hash codes must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

`Map`s in Java should be keyed on values that have `equals` defined over all their 'essential properties'. I believe most collection libraries work like this, with the only example that springs to mind is that of General Magic's Telescript.

So, have a `Map` defined on a type of only those properties. The `field1` `int` (`Integer`) in this case. Put the rest of the information in the map entry value. This may well be a new class.

```
Map<Integer, ValueClass> map;
```

where

```
public final class ValueClass {
    private int someValue;
    private ExampleClass exmaple;
    ...
```

If you are insistent you want to find the key, which I suggest you don't. There's various ways of doing it, something like:

```
Optional<ExampleClass> found = map.keySet().stream()
    .firstThat(k -> k.field1() == target);
found.ifPresent(key -> {
   Integer value = hmap.remove(key);
   // update key.
   hmap.put(key, value);
});
```

Or the old school version (looks better to me, but not so cool):

```
for (ExampleClass key : map.keySet()) {
    if (key.field1() == target) {
        Integer value = hmap.remove(key);
        // update key.
        hmap.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Using an `Iterator` or possibly over an ihe entry set is better in that it avoids the second of three lookups, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: I understand that for this particular example, it's better design to structure the classes differently, but it's difficult to do that for my code at this moment. Is there no way to get the key object matching an inputKey in a hash map?

Comment: @StephenLee You can, but it's really not the way you should be doing it.